# installing files in other usr

Tags: linux, installation

Do you know how can I install apps in other folder than `usr` automatically? (using `dpkg` and make install)

I want just to install it for example in special folder in my home partition (for example `/home/usr`).

Comment: May I ask why you want that?

Comment: Cause I have phone with 256 MB root and extandable to 27 GB home ?

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can't do it with `dpkg`, as files in the package expect each other to be put in specific places. If `dpkg` were to install things in other places, a lot of things simply wouldn't work. See (for example) [here](http://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2000/09/msg01903.html) for more details.

If the product uses a configure script, you can usually compile it with a `--prefix` option, which allows you to put the files in a non-standard location.

Answer (score 0):

If you can run `dpkg` on your phone and play with folders like this, I guess you can do other root'ish stuff to your phone.

I suppose you can mount, umount, and edit the automount table. If so, copy everything of your `/usr/` to `/home/usr/`:

```
mkdir /home/usr/
rsync -av /usr/ /home/usr/
```

and then mount the latter on the top of the former with the `bind` mount option, by adding this line to /etc/fstab/:

```
/home/usr /usr none bind
```

Finally reboot, and run

```
mount
```

to see if it worked.

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro,...)
/dev/sda2 on /home type ext4 (rw,...)
...
/home/usr on /usr type none (rw,bind)
```

Good luck!

Comment: The problem is I tried it and it won't work. Probably because that they're files needed before mount.

Comment: It doesn't even show on `mount`? Can you mount manually?